# Docker .Net Core app, trying to connect to SQL db

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, docker, .net-core

In Visual Studio 2017 I created an app using .Net Core 2 MVC project with Identity.  VS2017 builds the dockerfile and compose file for me.  The app itself builds successfully. VS also sets up the migrations and what not, all I have to do is run the migrations and it sets up and connects to the DB.  By default it does this to 'localDB,' and yes it works successfully this way.  My .Net Core app in docker successfully connects to a non-docker SQL db.  However, I want a SQL DB inside of docker to work with my app.

In an attempt to do this I only made two changes.  I changed the docker-compose file to this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  identity.api:
    image: identity.api
    build:
      context: ./Identity.api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - myapp

  identityDB:
    image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "Password01!"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    networks:
      - myapp


networks:
  myapp:
    driver: bridge
```

And my connection string to:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=identityDB;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=Password01!;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

The error I get is:

SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

```
        An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, object providerInfo, bool 
redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData
reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling)
```

When I move the Database container to start before the identity.api container, I get this error:

```
SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

Comment: Could be a timing problem. Your API starts before the database is available

Comment: Tried moving the DB above the api container, still doesn't work.  I added the error in the original post.

Comment: Have you tried starting simpler? Run an instance of the database container and then connect to it with SSMS. If that works, change your app container to connect to that database. If that works, then integrate the database container into your compose file.

Comment: Order of services in the docker compose file does not matter. Also, there's no standardized way for docker to know when a container is "up"

Comment: Try `docker-compose down -v; docker-compose up -d identityDB; sleep 15; docker-compose up -d identity.api;` This make sure you test after DB is up. If it works then it is a timing issue

Comment: Normally you can also add a dependency between api and db, but the mssql container takes time to start. I usually start the db first, wait a while and than start the api. You can use the wait-for-it script to start your api as soon as port 1433 on the db server is available. Look here: https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it